# Intellij debugging ignore files

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, intellij-idea

IntelliJ Idea (14.1.4) has an option to ignore certain Javascript files when debugging. The option can be found within:
Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger > Stepping

I've added the following as a file to ignore:

backbone.js

I've also ticked the box to ignore library scripts. However when stepping into a complex expression it will still drop me into backbone.js. Am I specifying something incorrectly or is this a bug in the IDE?

Edit:

Including a screen shot of my settings.
[image: IntelliJ settings]

Here is an example line that will send the debugger to backbone.js during a step into:

```
hostsCollection = new HostsCollection(this.model.get('hostcell').get('hosts'), {
  availableHostingPlans: this.availableHostingPlans
});
```

Since backbone.js is ignored it should be stepping over this line instead of into.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the stepping page with your settings?

Comment: Looks OK to me. Maybe try restarting? I'm not sure at this point. What type of app are you debugging?

Comment: Javascript. I've tried restarting with no luck. Not sure what else I can try here.